# How does the Snipping Tool in win7 persist it's "Save As" path?

Tags: c#, windows-7

It doesn't store it in the registry or a file.

It seems like it must persist the default path using the "Common Item Dialog", but how do can I find the actual path knowing this?  It seems like the info is supposed to be private to the app...(?)

Oddly, I don't even see msdn info about how to access the "Common Item Dialog" from dotnet, so I really need to go through all the interop hassle myself?

Then it's unclear how I'd obtain the GUID that Snipping Tool is using, so I can do things like:
GUID guid;
pfd->IdentifyDialog(&guid);

Comment: The older Common File Dialog "persisted" its path (only for the duration of execution) by changing the program's current directory.  I am not familiar with the newer edition of the dialog, but perhaps this is what it does.

Comment: The directory is persistent across different executions of the Snipping app.  There's more to it than just current dir.

Comment: Well obviously it has to be persisted somewhere; if it is persisted across reboots then it has to be the registry or the file system.  It is not wise to rely on implementation details, but if you really want to know you should be able to figure it out with Process Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The Snipping Tool in my copy of Win 7 uses the "Pictures" String Value in:
  HKEY_CURRENT-USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders

You can change a lot of "default" locations under this Key and get them out from under the deeply buried locations that Microsoft provides.